# Excel 2013 crashes when a second monitor is connected for extended screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop that I connect a second screen to (different resolution) and extend the screen (Windows 10). This causes Excel 2013 to crash frequently, sometimes when dragging to the second screen, sometimes before the window even appears.

Other Office programs are fine. The problem disappears if the second screen is disconnected, or set to "duplicate" as opposed to "extend". I have updated the graphics drivers, and tried to diesable graphics hardware acceleration in Excel to no avail.
Anything else I can try?

Comment: You may need to ask for Microsoft Support help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the Control Panel, choose Apps and Features, then scroll down the list to Excel 2013 or Microsoft Office 2013 (whichever you have). Click on Repair then Continue, and when that completes, reboot your PC and retest.

Comment: This did not resolve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed the latest updates for your Office 2013.

You can try to run Excel in safe mode (Type excel /safe in Run dialog) and check if Excel works smoothly. If it's fine under safe mode, please follow the steps in [the article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-a-stopped-working-error-when-i-start-office-applications-on-my-pc-52bd7985-4e99-4a35-84c8-2d9b8301a2fa) to disable Add-ins manually one by one to have a check.

[image]

In my opinion, the issue may be related to different resolutions and scales between two screens. You could try to modify the scales of two screens. Click Start menu > Settings > System > Scale and layout. For example, you may set 125% for both two screens.

[image]

If none of the operations above works, you may repair Office as @K7AAY said.